# How to set in Html code 0 as valid value and to display

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question about html code in angular app.

my question ist, is there also the ohter way to check if value null or undefined in a ngif

my code looks like this.

```
<div ngif= "value !== null and value !== undefinded">
 {{value}}
</div>
```

1. question is there the other way to check this if? because there is not only this div.

i can not do this:

```
<div ngif= "value">
 {{value}}
</div>
```

because if the value 0 is, ngif return false, But I expect also to display 0.

any better idea?

Comment: how about `ngif="value && value !== 0"`?

Comment: what will ngif return if value 0 is?

Comment: should be what value is

Answer (score 0):

Simply add exception if it's 0 to `ngif="value"` if you want to show 0: `ngif="value && value !== 0"`

**<kbd>[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8zscha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)</kbd>**